Trying to make an digital clock circuit however can't make it work as intended
As a project, my professor gave the class to make an digital clock circuit (no microprocessors allowed!). I have used a 555 timer, 6 SN74LS90N and 6 SN74LS47N IC and 6 5161BS 7-seg for the project. here is the schematic : 
and here is my circuit: 
And it's connections:

In proteus simulation, circuit works as intended however when built
Seconds flow normally it counts from 00 to 60 and resets however upon reseting minutes or hours digits doesn't advance
Here is a video of my circuit running
but the most dazzling thing is when you switch the displays of minute part the numbers on the displays are also switched! and I really can't wrap my head around that.
Here is a video to demonstrate
I am completely exhausted of this project I just answers to:

why my circuit i and how to fix it

why switching displays also switch the numbers
Thanks.



Please post a real schematic of the circuit, not a wiring diagram. Just from looking at your board, I'm going to guess your problem is solder bridge related. Start checking data lines to see if they match expected behavior and work backwards until you find something that isn't playing nicely.

Also, you are missing all of your power supply decoupling capacitors.

what does it do? ... isn't working does not really describe anything useful

Unusual definition of analogue!

That's not an analogue clock in any way.

Well, maybe in the sense that digital electronics is just a special case of analog(ue) ;)

A very warm welcome to the site. First, I'm afraid you're not understanding 'analogue' and 'digital'. It looks like a digital logic circuit. Secondly, it's a Q&A site and can't be a personal tutorial or free debugging service. Thirdly, its your project to own, research, design, fault-find and polish so "I am completely exhausted of this project, I just (want) answers to..." is the opposite of what you need. It might not be what you'd want to hear but you won't learn anything if you're fed the answers. Please edit your question (not in comments) add lot more detail on what you've done so far.

@JohnD, digital electronics is just convenient analogue electronics. But all that's a long way from understanding the terms and using 'em properly in engineering :-)

ARDA Adsiz - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "áccepting" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either your answer (which can be áccepted after 2024-05-16 @ 16.33 UTC i.e. 48 hrs after the question was asked) or another answer (which can be accepted any time) if one is written & if you consider it the best one. That shows you don't need more help & consider the problem solved. TY

I solved the problem: I had soldered a wire wrongly. All of the "switching displays switches numbers" was because of the fact one of my displays was faulty and showed '8' as '9'. Since mı segment was set as 88, it displayed as 98 or 89 depending on the location of the faulty display.
Thanks for the explanations and how the site works I am kinda new to this stack exchange stuff. I always thought analogue as if it has computers it's digital else analogue. Sorry for inconvenience and thanks for criticism I will try harder next time.
